# Why does my directive lose $event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive to confirm if a user that clicks an element really wants to perform an action:

```
  .directive('ngReallyClick', ['$modal',
    function ($modal) {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                ngReallyClick: "&",
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var isDeleteDisabled = scope.ngReallyDisabled;
                element.bind('click', function () {
                    if (isDeleteDisabled != true) {
                        var message = attrs.ngReallyMessage || "Are you sure ?";
                        ...
                        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                            template: modalHtml,
                            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
                        });

                        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                            scope.ngReallyClick({ ngReallyItem: scope.ngReallyItem }); //raise an error : $digest already in progress
                        }, function () {
                            //Modal dismissed
                            return false;
                        });
                    };
                });

            }
        }
    }]);
```

It is used e.g:

```
<a ng-really-message="Are you sure you want to save and close?" ng-really-click="saveAndCloseGlobal(456)"
```

where `saveAndCloseGlobal` is called when the user confirms their choice. But, if I try and pass `$event` to this function, to get the original `click` event, it ends up undefined. If I use a plain `ng-click=saveAndCloseGlobal($event)` then I get the correct event object in `saveAndCloseGlobal`.

Comment: I imagine it's because `ng-click` is a different directive and they handled it, you're binding a different event. Why not do `element.bind('click', function (event) {` and use that ?

Comment: The `ngReallyClick` directive has a whole host of target functions, and I'm trying to not mess with the parameters passed to them  in the `ng-really-click` attribute. I'll see if I can work something, thanks.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to add a new one, you're already doing the `element.bind('click', function () { ... })`. I'm just saying add the event parameter, no HTML changes needed :)

Comment: @OmriAharon My concern is how to send the `event` passed to `bind` to my end function, not how to get that event object in the directive code itself.

Comment: What is ModalInstanceCtrl?  Why don't you just set scope: scope in the modal open?  i.e., pass the current scope from the link function to the scope of the modal.  Then you can just put your close function directly in the link function.

Comment: @jme I'm trying to make minimum changes to a large project already using this directive.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, got your intention now. I think I know why, try to change the scope binding from `&` to `=` and in the HTML pass the function reference (i.e., `saveAndCloseGlobal` instead of `saveAndCloseGlobal(..)`.

Comment: I get it, but where's your ModalInstanceCtrl defined?  Usually, if you're using this approach, you'd use the resolve property in order to pass data and behaviors to the modal instance.  The $modal is a service and resolve works like resolve in ngRoute.  My point was that you can just pass the current scope directly on to the scope of the modal service.  I'm just not clear why that would cause widespread changes for you.  I guess it would be easier to see it in context in a Plunker or something.

Comment: Ahh...lightbulb...now I see what you're doing.

Comment: So why not just wrap the click in a $timeout so it doesn't raise an error?

Comment: @OmriAharon But then how do I pass other arguments to e.g. `saveAndCloseGlobal` or other 'click' functions? I think I might just have to duplicate and change the whole directive, to do what I want.

Comment: Basically if you have the function reference in `scope.ngReallyClick` you can now invoke it with whatever params you want, so you could do `scope.ngReallyClick(event, myParam1, myParam2, etc..);`

Comment: You can maybe add some attributes to the directive to pass the params.

Comment: You already have the solution: `scope.ngReallyClick({ ngReallyItem: scope.ngReallyItem });`. Just add the event.